# C comparing 2 doubles returns wrong result

Tags: c

I am comparing two doubles like the following:

```
bool isbig = fabs(sin1 - sin(x)) > 0.000001;
if (isbig)
    printf("fabs=%f, max=%f", fabs(sin1-sin(x)), 0.000001);
```

Now, for some reason it prints in the output:

fabs=0.000001, max=0.000001

Why doesn't the comparison work? The print should only work if the left side is bigger than the right, but in the print we can see the sides are equal. Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: Print more digits.

Comment: By print more digits do you mean try comparing different numbers?

Comment: I mean print more digits, i.e. `%.17f`.

Answer (score 2):

The `%f` format specifier to `printf` rounds to 6 decimal places by default, so it's entirely possible that `fabs` is something like `0.00000125` or `0.0000010064`.  Try something like `%.16f` to see more digits, and you should see `fabs` larger than `max`.

(And if you notice that `max` doesn't print as `0.00000100000000000000`, go read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.))

Comment: Thanks. Then how do I compare to the accuracy of the first 6 digits?

Comment: @INTODAN That is the subject of a totally different question. ;)